# Why is there a ng-src and not a ng-href?

Tags: angularjs

I have a question about Angular (the code comes from the Angular tutorial)

It's about this code:
 `<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>`

The tutorial says:

> [...]using an image tag with the `ngSrc` directive. That directive
>   prevents the browser from treating the Angular `{{ expression }}`
>   markup literally

However, in the same line of code, there is this part:
`<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}"`

in which the same construct is used, namely the value of a property in a `string`.

Imho the `href=""` and the `src=""` are both properties of a html tag, but for `img` there is a separate directive (`ng-src`) but for the `A` tag there is no `ng-href` directive?

PS
I'm a .Net dev, newbee to Angular

Comment: Right! Will edit :-)

Comment: Shame on me :-( Looking on the example I just concluded there was none. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) for links. It is the `ng-src` for links you are looking for.

Comment: Shame on me :-( Looking on the example I just concluded there was none. Thanks.